# selecting asp TableCell control by class not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to select asp TableCells by class (which I set by using `tableCellName.Attributes.Add("class","class_name")`) using jQuery (`$("class_name").get()`) but the list it collects is empty. I do a similar thing with asp TableRows and jQuery finds those elements, so I'm wondering: is there something different about the way jQuery interacts with TableCells?

Comment: you should use $('.className') to select anything with class. try reading here https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: Check your html and verify that your td is in there with the assumed class.  And what is the get() for? You can also do: $("class_name").each(function() { //Do something });

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".class_name").get()
  /|\ 
this dot 
is super
important
```